# Import variables from another .dart file to .dart file in flutter

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart

My globals.dart file in same directory:

```
var apiKey= "AAAAXeuC-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX0rKLb2CWty0MHUzaZ";
var appId= "1:40338f8d8e";
var messagingSenderId= "40338";
var projectId="XXXXXXXXXXXXX";
var databaseURL= "XXXXXXXXXXXX";
```

I want to import these variables to main.dart file in android studio.
How I did??

```
import 'globals.dart' as globals;
```

Imported correctly, no errors
How I used??

```
apiKey: globals.apiKey
```

Its inside,

```
  if(Firebase.apps.isNotEmpty){
    await Firebase.initializeApp(
      name: "HCchatbot",
      options: const FirebaseOptions(
          apiKey: ,
          appId: ,
          messagingSenderId:,
          projectId: ,
          databaseURL:"
      ),
    );
  }
```

The error:

```
lib/main.dart:12:27: Error: Not a constant expression.
          apiKey: globals.apiKey,
                          ^^^^^^
lib/main.dart:11:22: Error: Constant evaluation error:
      options: const FirebaseOptions(
                     ^
lib/main.dart:12:27: Context: The invocation of 'apiKey' is not allowed in a constant expression.
          apiKey: globals.apiKey,
                          ^
```

Can somebody help me out?? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

all of your values in globals.dart should be turned to const values =>

```
const String apiKey= "AAAAXeuC-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX0rKLb2CWty0MHUzaZ";
const String appId= "1:40338f8d8e";
const String messagingSenderId= "40338";
const String projectId="XXXXXXXXXXXXX";
const String databaseURL= "XXXXXXXXXXXX";
```

try again and it should work.

another solution is removing the const in the FirebaseOptions

```
options: FirebaseOptions
```

Comment: You can also wrap it around a class like `Globals` and make all declare the values like `static const String apiKey = "ABC";` And in main file use them like `Globals.apiKey`. Having everything in a class would make it cleaner.